# Cannot access Web Service (asmx) from host machine (running IIS 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.android

I have simple web service (asmx) running on my PC using port 7778. 
I've assigned the app pool (v2), port forwarded 7778 on my router to resolve to my local IP address (192.168.1.2)  that I've set up manually (static local ip address). I've also used NoIP's service for DNS and this is checking if my non static real Ip address changes.
when I try to connect to:
http://mynoipdnsname.no-ip.biz:7778/Service1.asmx from any computer outside my local network
It's all working, 
using: 
localhost:7778/Service1.asmx       or 
192.168.1.2:7778/Service1.asmx
from my local PC works fine. 
The problem is that when I try:
http://mynoipdnsname.no-ip.biz:7778/Service1.asmx 
from my local computer (192.168.1.2) 
it's not getting the data.
I have Android app, when I try to add web service's  url: 
http://mynoipdnsname.no-ip.biz:7778/Service1.asmx
I get error message:

> Unable to connect to the remote server No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it

Any ideas what I've missed?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. My windows firewall and router firewall are turned off.

Comment: From your local computer you can ping mynoipdnsname.no-ip.biz ? Try to add mynoipdnsname mynoipdnsname.no-ip.biz to your hosts file ? Your IIS site has authentication ?

Comment: Thank you @Max! Adding this to my Hosts file worked! Can you please post your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add mynoipdnsname.no-ip.biz to your hosts file or your DNS.